# How can I get generalized statistics of the StackExchange user base?

Tags: feature-request, community-data

I'd like to get some statistics, anonymized, about the StackExchange userbase--at this point, mainly where people are located, but eventually other information.

Is this possible?

Comment: [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange has a service called the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that allows you to run SQL queries against public data from SE sites.  It includes the location attribute for users.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'll accept this answer as soon as SO lets me.